# How to upload ZIP File from API Management to Blob Storage

Tags: c#, xml, azure, azure-api-management, azure-blob-storage

1. I am sending a POST Request on one of my Azure Api Mangement APIs
2. In this post request there is a json body which contains base64 encoded data (zip file) like in this example:

   {
       "foo": "bar",
       "data": "your-base64-string"
   }
3. In the API Policy, I want to send a separate request to the Azure Storage REST API to save the above mentioned base64 string as a zip file.

Now the problem: 
I can successfully send a request to the Azure Storage REST API and download the resulting zip file via this statement:

```
<set-body>@{
var base64String = (string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("body")["data"]) ;
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); 
var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); 
return ascii; 
}</set-body>
```

The thing is, I can download and open the zip file but I cannot extract the content of it as the archive got damaged.

Here is an example base64 encoded zip file string (ZIP File containing a text.txt):

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIAL1ZxE7MTbG/EwAAABMAAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHQLycgsVgCiRIWS1OKStMycVD0AUEsBAh8AFAAAAAgAvVnETsxNsb8TAAAAEwAAAAgAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAHRlc3QudHh0CgAgAAAAAAABABgAI8Ac2LUa1QEjwBzYtRrVAZFuI861GtUBUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAWgAAADkAAAAAAA==
```

Here is my code for posting it to the Rest API:

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="putStorageRequest" timeout="5" ignore-error="true">
            <set-url>@((string)context.Variables["blobUrl"])</set-url>
            <set-method>PUT</set-method>
            <set-header name="x-ms-date" exists-action="override">
                <value>@((string) context.Variables["date"] )</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="x-ms-version" exists-action="override">
                <value>@((string) context.Variables["version"] )</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="x-ms-blob-type" exists-action="override">
                <value>BlockBlob</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/zip</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@{
                        string body = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
                        string contentType = "application/zip";
                        var base64String = (string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("body")["data"]) ;
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); 
            var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
                        var contentLength = ascii.Length;
                        var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageKey")) };
                        var payLoad = string.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n\n{2}\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{3}\nx-ms-version:{4}\n{5}", 
                            "PUT", 
                            contentLength,
                            contentType,
                            context.Variables["date"],
                            context.Variables["version"],
                            "/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageAccountName") + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("resource"));
                        return "SharedKey "+ context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageAccountName") + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad)));
                    }</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                var base64String = (string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("body")["data"]) ;
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); 
                var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); 
                return ascii;         
            }</set-body>
        </send-request>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand you want to upload or download the file ?

Comment: I want to upload the file using the Azure Storage REST API. The download is unnecessary for this point. Its all about the Encoding from the Upload. Hope you understand it now!

Comment: Ok I see, so the base64 encoded zip file is valid and contains a `test.txt` file with this content `This is a testfile.` ? The problem is that you should not convert it back to string `var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);`. You should send the raw bytes to the storage api. could you share your code that do the upload ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: So i just uploaded the code.

Comment: So can you try removing this line `var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)` in both header and body ? get the contentlenght from bytes.Lenght and return the bytes array for the body.

Comment: So i just tried it. But the problem here is that the Blob Storage only accepts strings and not byte arrays.

Comment: in your body can you try to return a stream: `var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); return new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));`. Blob storage accepts any type of file, the trick is to do it with API Management ^^

Comment: Yeah, you said it already.. Its not supported in API Management... so how can i proceed here?

Comment: can you not handle it in code ? pushing to a function app for example ?

Comment: Well, im doing it right now, But it's "unclean" if you know what i mean. It would be better handling the call inside of an API. But if there is no other solution, there is no other option left. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Another solution would be a logic app, as it allows setting binary request bodies.
So one could simply add a "Create Blob" operation and set the body to following string: @base64toBinary(triggerBody()['body'][data']).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure API Management now supports byte[] in body:

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-update-september-2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-update-september-2019/)

> The set-body policy also accepts byte array as body content.

My test was successful by creating a zip-file in Blob-Storage, downloaded it, opened the zip-file and opened the containing Text-file.

Following code was used:

```
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
                    string body = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
                    string contentType = "application/zip";
                    var base64String = (string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("body")["data"] ;
                    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); 
                    var contentLength = bytes.Length;
                    var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageKey")) };
                    var payLoad = string.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n\n{2}\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{3}\nx-ms-version:{4}\n{5}", 
                        "PUT", 
                        contentLength,
                        contentType,
                        context.Variables["date"],
                        context.Variables["version"],
                        "/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageAccountName") + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("resource"));
                    return "SharedKey "+ context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("storageAccountName") + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad)));
                }</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{
            var base64String = (string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("body")["data"] ;
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String); 
            return bytes;         
        }</set-body>
```

I just had to remove:

```
var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```